# Excel VBA - Refer to a worksheet as a variable in an IF statement

Tags: excel, vba, variables, worksheet

In the following piece of VBA code, how do I replace the reference to the worksheet 'ContolPage' with the variable 'cPage'?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[5]="""","""",ControlPage!R[-13]C[-2])"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove any vba variable from the quotes and concatenate with `&`:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[5]="""","""",'" & cPage & "'!R[-13]C[-2])"
```

Comment: Remember that if this works for you to click on the check mark by the answer to mark as correct.  It is something only the one who posed the question can do, after the question has been open for around 17 minutes.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Scott.  I did try this concatenation previously but it seems it was failing because I had a hyphen in the worksheet name (and variable).

Comment: @OneBigEgg see edit, made a change to wrap the sheet name in `'...'` which should allow for the hyphen